# Flutter SfDataGrid PDF export not displaying StackedHeader and Footer

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, sfdatagrid

I want to export the SFDataGrid to PDF including the StackedHeader and Footer but it is always empty. Sample code below

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid/datagrid.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_pdf/pdf.dart' as sf_pdf;
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_datagrid_export/export.dart';
import 'package:printing/printing.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Employee> employees = [
      Employee(10001, 'James', 'Project Lead', 20000),
      Employee(10002, 'Kathryn', 'Manager', 30000),
      Employee(10003, 'Lara', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10004, 'Michael', 'Designer', 15000),
      Employee(10005, 'Martin', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10006, 'Newberry', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10007, 'Balnc', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10008, 'Perry', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10009, 'Gable', 'Developer', 15000),
      Employee(10010, 'Grimes', 'Developer', 15000)
    ];

    GlobalKey<SfDataGridState> key = GlobalKey<SfDataGridState>();
    EmployeeDataSource employeeDataSource =
        EmployeeDataSource(employees: employees);
    void exportDataGridToPDF() async {
      sf_pdf.PdfDocument document = key.currentState!.exportToPdfDocument();
      final List<int> bytes = document.saveSync();

      await Printing.layoutPdf(onLayout: (_) => Uint8List.fromList(bytes));
      document.dispose();
    }

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            SfDataGrid(
              key: key,
              source: employeeDataSource,
              stackedHeaderRows: [
                StackedHeaderRow(
                  cells: [
                    StackedHeaderCell(
                      columnNames: ['id', 'name', 'designation', 'salary'],
                      child: const Text("Stacked Header"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
              footer: const Text("FOOTER"),
              columns: [
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 'id',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: const Text(
                          'ID',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ))),
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 'name',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Name',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ))),
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 'designation',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Designation',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ))),
                GridColumn(
                    columnName: 'salary',
                    label: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                        child: const Text(
                          'Salary',
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ))),
              ],
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => exportDataGridToPDF(),
                child: const Text("Export to PDF"))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Employee {
  Employee(this.id, this.name, this.designation, this.salary);
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final String designation;
  final int salary;
}

class EmployeeDataSource extends DataGridSource {
  EmployeeDataSource({required List<Employee> employees}) {
    dataGridRows = employees
        .map<DataGridRow>((dataGridRow) => DataGridRow(cells: [
              DataGridCell<int>(columnName: 'id', value: dataGridRow.id),
              DataGridCell<String>(columnName: 'name', value: dataGridRow.name),
              DataGridCell<String>(
                  columnName: 'designation', value: dataGridRow.designation),
              DataGridCell<int>(
                  columnName: 'salary', value: dataGridRow.salary),
            ]))
        .toList();
  }

  List<DataGridRow> dataGridRows = [];

  @override
  List<DataGridRow> get rows => dataGridRows;

  @override
  DataGridRowAdapter? buildRow(DataGridRow row) {
    return DataGridRowAdapter(
        cells: row.getCells().map<Widget>((dataGridCell) {
      return Container(
          alignment: (dataGridCell.columnName == 'id' ||
                  dataGridCell.columnName == 'salary')
              ? Alignment.centerRight
              : Alignment.centerLeft,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Text(
            dataGridCell.value.toString(),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          ));
    }).toList());
  }
}
```

Output
[image: Output]

My other option is to create a custom footer using `DataGridToPdfConverter` - `DataGridPdfHeaderFooterExportCallback` but I can't find how to get the position of the bottom of the datatable in the output. Basically, I want to create a footer just below the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

To display StackedHeader in exported documents, set the StackedHeaderCell's text property.
I can't help you with the footer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).